# Does a PostgreSQL connection use gzip?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, gzip

I'm running a pure [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) app on Heroku with a [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) database. I'm using the [Pg Ruby gem](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/) to communicate with the database.

When my application server sends queries to my PostgreSQL database server, is each request from my application server gzipped? What about each response from the PostgreSQL server?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you should be using TLS, and encryption and compression don't mix (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH)